# Load previous appsettings.json file if the current json file is not formatted properly

Tags: asp.net-core

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, 
                    reloadOnChange: true).SetFileLoadExceptionHandler(ctx => {
                        //Load the previous working appsettings.json file if any
                     });
```

The above code loads appsettings.json which is in startup.cs. There is an option for users to modify appsettings.json file. If the modified file is not formatted properly I want to use the previous file.

Ex:

```
appsettings.json [Proper json format]

    {
      "Conn" : "Test"
    }

appsettings.json [Modified, not a proper json format]

    {
      "Conn"
    }
```

So, whenever user changes the appsettings.json the file is reloaded into application. Since, the modified json file is not formatted properly, it goes to `SetFileLoadExceptionHandler`. In the handler I would like to load the previous json file instead of modified file.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: No. There's no way to do this. No history is kept. Once the file is changed it's changed. It's possible you could create a custom config provider that would do something like pull a previous commit from your source control, but that's entirely on you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt is there a way to copy the proper JSON file to a backup file and then replace whenever there is an exception ?

Comment: Again, not out of the box, but you can make ASP.NET Core do pretty much anything you want it to. It's all middleware, so you could implement an IHostService that backs up the JSON file and then a custom config provider that restores the backup on error. You'll need to do your own research on that though.

Comment: However, personally, I'd say the real solution is a robust check-in procedure and automated builds/testing. A malformed JSON should never make it to master, let alone published to production. If appsettings.json is getting jacked live, your publish procedures need an overhaul.